# admob rewarded video limit

Tags: video, admob, impressions

I use admob rewarded video. I set the limit of impressions to 5 per hour. But how can I check on client when the limit is reached, without implementing my own checking system.

I want to avoid to send a request when there is no reward video available anymore.

Comment: *I want to avoid to send a request when there is no reward video available anymore.*. Why? That's the whole purpose of limiting it on AdMob so you don't have to do this in your application.

Comment: Because I want to avoid unnecessary requests. For example, it would be nice if there was an extra error-code at the onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad (int errorCode) method. Then I would know I don't have to repeat the request because the limit is reached.

Comment: Why not create a counter that increments in the ad did close delegate method and then check it before each request?

Comment: Because I want to be able to dynamically change my admob limit settings. So maybe tomorrow the limit will be 5 impressions per day. Furthermore, I would have to store the counter locally to avoid cheating by closing the app. There must be a simple sophisticated solution from admob.

Comment: The simplest solution is to just send the requests and change the impression limit on AdMob. There isn't a way to accomplish what you're describing without building your own backend. Are you trying to change your UI based on if you have an ad or not? Use `.isReady` if that's the case.

Comment: Okay I accept if there is no way to do it with a build in method. I am aware of .isReady but this wont help to attempt the simple idea to avoid sending unnecessary requests. Which shouldn't be my personal guidelines. I wonder if other developers simple fire requests, regardless if the limit is reached or not.